# Decelerating function property, calculus

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a $C^2$ function satisfying:
$$f(x)>0,\quad f'(x)>0, \quad f''(x)<0, \quad \textrm{for}\quad x>0.$$
Show that 
$$x,y>0 \implies f(x+y) <f(x)+f(y).$$

This is very intuitively obvious to me, because this function is monotonically increasing but concave down. However, I don't know how to show it analytically. I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Imagine a scenario which breaks the result above .. with your intuition behind you, show that that is impossible

Comment: I can set up the proof by contradiction but I don't really know where to go from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to begin with the limit case where $f'(x)>0$ and $f''(x)=0$, so the function is increasing linearly. In this case, as $f(x)>0$, we find
$$f(x+y)=f(x)+y*f'(x)\leq f(x)+f(y)$$
The equality is saturated when $f(x)=x$. Now, if $f''(x)<0$, meaning that $f'(x)$ is decreasing with $x$, we find
$$f(x+y)<f(x)+y*f'(x)$$
If we suppose that $y\leq x$ (similar reasoning can be done for $x\leq y$), we have that $y*f'(x)<y*f'(y)<f(y)$ we arrive to the final solution:
$$f(x+y)<f(x)+f(y)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For each fixed $x,$ show the function $y\to f(x) + f(y)-f(x+y), y \in [0,\infty),$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: Simplest possible answer +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly:

Write $y=x+t$ and consider

$h(t)=f(x)+f(x+t)-f(2x+t)$.

$h'(t)=f'(x+t)-f'(2x+t)=-(f'(2x+t)-f'(x+t))-xf''(c)$ for some

$x+t<c<2x+t$.

To finish, observe that $-xf''(c)>0$ from which it follows that $h$ is increasing on $(x,y)$.

Comment: Where do you get the second derivative term on your h'(t) line from?

Comment: The Mean Value Theorem.